# Why does my button translate when I want it to scale?

Tags: css, css-animations

What is supposed to happen: Button grows slightly when hovered over.
What does happen: Button grows slightly when hovered over and move to the right.

How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
#skipButton
{

    border-radius: 10em;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, Pink, Magenta);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, Pink, Magenta);
    background: radial-gradient(center, Pink, Magenta);
    border: none;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    outline: none;
    padding: .25em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#skipButton:hover
{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you're scaling *and* translating. You're implicitly translating back to 0 on hover, since it's already been set. You need this:

```
#skipButton:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%) scale(1.25);
}
```